# Can a template's generic type be scoped in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, scope, template-function

I'm trying to scope to the generic type of a template, like this:

`template<typename T> void doSomething(T::SomeScopedType t) {...}`

However, this leads to the compiler errors:

`variable or field ‘doSomething’ declared void
expected ‘)’ before ‘t'`

Is it possible to scope a generic type?

Comment: Use the `typename` keyword to instruct the compiler that `T::SomeScopedType` names a type, e.g. `... doSomething(typename T::SomeScopedType t) ...`.  A call to `doSomething` will likely need to be explicitly instantiated (e.g. `doSomething<SomeType>(...);` (T = SomeType).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware an answer had already existed